# ActiveMQ: Store message to string in python

Tags: python, activemq-classic

I would like to store the message I get from a queue in ActiveMQ to a string but I can't find out how to do it. My code is as follows:

```
import stomp
import time

class SampleListener(object):
  def on_message(self, headers, msg):
    print(msg)

conn = stomp.Connection10()

conn.set_listener('SampleListener', SampleListener())

conn.start()

conn.connect()

conn.subscribe('test2')



time.sleep(1) # secs

conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: Store it to a string where? On disk?

Comment: @roganjosh On the code, so I can use it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class you are only ***printing*** the messages which you receive, you'll need to:

- Store the messages in a list
- Instantiate the class "SampleListener" and return the list

See additions to your code below.

```
import stomp
import time

class SampleListener(object):

  #define your empty list used to store the messages
  def __init__(self):
    self.message_list = []

  def on_message(self, headers, msg):

    # appends new msg to message_list
    self.message_list.append((headers, msg))

    # comment this out if you dont want to print all msgs to console
    print(msg) 

conn = stomp.Connection10()

# instantiate the class
listener = SampleListener()

conn.set_listener('SampleListener', listener)

conn.start()

conn.connect()

conn.subscribe('test2')



time.sleep(1) # secs

conn.disconnect()

# messages received during the 1 second period stored in a list called "myMessages"
myMessages = listener.message_list
```